# Is it ok to bend the style guide sometimes?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, and am taking a java course, and part of it is that it teaches you correct code style.

Given this switch statement:

```
switch (number) {
    case 1 -> {
        return "Mon";
    }
    case 2 -> {
        return "Tue";
    }
    case 3 -> {
        return "Wed";
    }
    case 4 -> {
        return "Thu";
    }
    case 5 -> {
        return "Fri";
    }
    case 6 -> {
        return "Sat";
    }
    case 7 -> {
        return "Sun";
    }
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Is it acceptable to style it like this?:

```
switch (number) {
    case 1 -> {return "Mon";}
    case 2 -> {return "Tue";}
    case 3 -> {return "Wed";}
    case 4 -> {return "Thu";}
    case 5 -> {return "Fri";}
    case 6 -> {return "Sat";}
    case 7 -> {return "Sun";}
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

It's much more concise, and it is easier to read. However, the java course automatically flags it as bad code style. Is this ok, or is it frowned upon?

Comment: Code style depends per team, for example, a certain project may have a certain code style. In your case, I think it is fine as you are taking a course and not working with others.

Comment: You're taking a course, and the course is teaching you coding style.  Are you asking whether it shouldn't be?

Comment: In a course, I'd stick to the rules the teacher has set. In the 'real world', the rules are usually a team decision. It will also depend on how much of the style is enforced by automatic tools.

Comment: Different projects have different code styles.  In the codebase I work on, your version would not be permitted.

Comment: You don't need any of these `{` or `}` in the first place. Rule 1: don't write redundant syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can extract all the `return`s out of the switch like this:

```
return switch (number) {
    case 1 ->  "Mon";
    case 2 -> "Tue";
    case 3 -> "Wed";
    case 4 -> "Thu";
    case 5 -> "Fri";
    case 6 -> "Sat";
    case 7 -> "Sun";
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
};
```

Then you don't have to worry about violating the rule about statements and `}` must go on a new line - you don't have statements or `}` in your switch any more :)